# Font for the names of logic gates

Tags: fonts, logic

[image]

What command could I use to change the font for logic gate names, such as NOT and XOR, so that it looks like what is

Comment: The NOT, XOR... in the above figure seems to be the `\scshape` of Computer Modern Serif.

Comment: In the below figure it seems to be `\scshape` of Courier.